# Explaining the size of the canadian banking sector

Tags: banking, canada

Canadian banks are among the largest in the world and I think that only the UK compares in terms of having your economy dominated by banking. Of course some of the US banks are much larger but so is the country's population.

Searching on the subject doesn't lead me anywhere, I suspect that the big 5 of Canada do a good job of exporting financial services (of which none shows up in the trade balance, if I'm correct) and that Canada somehow provides advantages to its big 5 that other countries cannot compete with. Having said that, I would like to know what those predisposition that lead to the growth of a banking industry.